# Calculate Pi with output delay

Tags: java, loops, delay, pi

I want to to calculate an given amount of digits, or I want give an ouptut every 10 second. But I don't have much experiance, and i don't know how to make that possible. I tried to make it possible for about 5 hours, but i came to no conclusion.
Thank you for your time and help!

```
import java.math.BigInteger;

public class ProjectOne {

    final BigInteger TWO = BigInteger.valueOf(2);
    final BigInteger THREE = BigInteger.valueOf(3);
    final BigInteger FOUR = BigInteger.valueOf(4);
    final BigInteger SEVEN = BigInteger.valueOf(7);

    BigInteger a = BigInteger.ONE;
    BigInteger b = BigInteger.ZERO;
    BigInteger c = BigInteger.ONE;
    BigInteger d = BigInteger.ONE;
    BigInteger e = BigInteger.valueOf(3);
    BigInteger f = BigInteger.valueOf(3);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ProjectOne g = new ProjectOne();
        g.Stellenwerte();
    }

    public void Stellenwerte() {
        BigInteger nn, nr;
        boolean first = true;
        while (true) {
            if (FOUR.multiply(a).add(b).subtract(c).compareTo(e.multiply(c)) == -1) {
                System.out.print(e);
                if (first) {
                    System.out.print(".");
                    first = false;
                }
                nr = BigInteger.TEN.multiply(b.subtract(e.multiply(c)));
                e = BigInteger.TEN.multiply(THREE.multiply(a).add(b)).divide(c).subtract(BigInteger.TEN.multiply(e));
                a = a.multiply(BigInteger.TEN);
                b = nr;
                System.out.flush();
            } else {
                nr = TWO.multiply(a).add(b).multiply(f);
                nn = a.multiply((SEVEN.multiply(d))).add(TWO).add(b.multiply(f)).divide(c.multiply(f));
                a = a.multiply(d);
                c = c.multiply(f);
                f = f.add(TWO);
                d = d.add(BigInteger.ONE);
                e = nn;
                b = nr;
            }
        }
    }

    public static void delay(int milliseconds) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(milliseconds);
        } catch (InterruptedException exp) {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  It looks like you are asking for homework help.  While we have no issues with that per se, please observe these [dos and don'ts](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions/338845#338845), and edit your question accordingly.

Comment: No, its no Homework. It's a challange of our teacher. He said that probably no one could solve that. I mastered the challange, but i want to make it faster. Because you have to want a few minutes until you get the answer, because it has an constant output.